# Properties of Even Functions

Tags: function

I'm studying random variables and am given a solution that I cannot understand. Why do even functions reduced increasing part of the equation. Here are the equations:

$ f_y \ (y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} \ [f_x\ (\sqrt{y}) \ +f_x\ (-\sqrt{y})]u(y)$

and

$ f_x(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\{-x^2/2\} $

book says beacuse $f_x (x)$ is even, first equation equals to

$f_y (y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}f_x (\sqrt{y})u(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}} \exp\{-y^2/2\} u(y)$

I couldn't understand why we omit $f_x (-\sqrt{y}) $ part because $f_x (x)$ is even.

Comment: I think using x or y as a subscript to f is not necessary and causes confusion.

Comment: @Michael it is of course necessary. Otherwise, how can I know which pdf is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even functions have the following property $f(x) = f(-x)$
$f_x(x)$ is even so $f_x(x) = f_x(-x) \implies f_x(\sqrt y) = f_x(-\sqrt y)$

So the parenthesis in the first equation becomes $f_x(\sqrt y) + f_x(-\sqrt y) = 2f_x(\sqrt y)$

Therefore $f_y(y) = \frac {1} {2\sqrt y}[f_x(\sqrt y) + f_x(-\sqrt y)]u(y) = \frac {1} {2\sqrt y}[2f_x(\sqrt y)]u(y) = \frac {1} {\sqrt y}f_x(\sqrt y)u(y)$

Comment: I am more familiar with calling this a symmetry property. it is symmetric about 0.

Comment: @Michael "Symmetric about 0" is fine.  However, "even" is a standard term, usually taught to math students by the time they study Calculus.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions.

Comment: @whuber That is fine.  I didn't say it was not standard. I just said that I was unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: @Michael Comments are for asking for clarification or offering useful additional remarks. This site is not a place to be telling the world about what you might or might not be familiar with--please save that for chat and other less formal social media.